# Modify scale information to user-defined scale when creating raster tilemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis

When using the  spatial tool 'qmetatile' to create a raster tilemap in QGIS,
the layers for the desired scales do not appear as expected.
So, I want to create raster tiles for each level with my desired layer scale.

Is there a way to modify the spatial tool or use a different spatial tool as a solution?